# which is the optimized method

Tags: php, android, query-optimization, data-transfer

to receive and transmit data from "web-server having php website" to "android application", which is the best optimized method. Mean may it is json communication or api communication or uri or rest?

Comment: You're asking so much questions in one question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json is the best reliable method for communication between android and php, as you can add key and value pair for secure communication and also it takes very little bandwidth comparing others.